# How to show a local image using MediaItem for artUri from audio_service flutter

Tags: flutter, image, just-audio

Using [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service/example) how to show a local image asset (for the artUri) with MediaItem class instead of an image fetched from online.

The below code returns: No host specified in URI.

```
  static final _item = MediaItem(
    id: 'asset:///assets/audio/fireplace.mp3',
    album: "Timer",
    title: "Fireplace",
    artist: "Timer Inc",
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 5739820),
    artUri: Uri.parse('asset:///assets/images/fireplace.png'),
  );
```